# Why does letting $x,y,z \to 0$ to minimize the surface area of a box with an open lid violate the constraint $V - xyz = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, volume, lagrange-multiplier

I find this exercise to be very interesting and irksome that I can't seem to figure it out:

[image]

My thought process is as follows:

---

## 1.

Our surface area has no lid, so it can be shown as:

$$SA = 2zy + xy + 2xz$$

As there is only $1$ $xy$ square in the surface area. In terms of volume, $x$, and $y$, this is:

$$SA = \frac{2V}{x} + xy + \frac{2V}{y}$$

## 2.

This part is kind of bizarre to me in what it is exactly asking, but I can make this expression even more in terms of $V$:

$$SA = \frac{2V}{x} + \frac{V}{z} + \frac{2V}{y}$$

Now, I don't see how it's at all illogical to just assume, for the area to be a minimum, we make $x$, $y$, and $z$ tend to $0$ s.t. in our first equation that is only in terms of $x,y,$ and $z$, it will return a very small surface area. However, this is definitely not the answer anyone is looking for.

My lecture proceeded to do the following:

- Found the partial derivatives of the expression I found in **1.**
- Expressed all of them in terms of $V$.
- Used the expression $\nabla = F_{xx}F_{yy} - (F_{xy})^2$ to find saddle points and extrema to evaluate whether the expressions made for $x,y,z$ render a minimum, which it did.

However, I don't understand the thought process behind why this answers the question, I guess because I don't understand by "the area to be a minimum".

## 3.

According to my lecturer, this, in terms of Lagrange multipliers, says the following:

We wish to minimize $2zy + xy + 2xz$ subject to the constraint $V - xyz = 0$. This makes intuitive sense to me. However, I still don't see how there can be a *minimized area* .

---

EDIT:

My question seems to boil down to the fact that I haven't yet understood why considering the minimization of the surface area of a box with an open lid is not the trivial let $x,y,z $ be very close but not equal to $0$ which will make the surface area infinitesimally small, and how the constraint $V - xyz = 0$ doesn't allow for this. $x,y,z$ are the side lengths of the box. Winding down the values each close to $0$ will minimze the area, in my view, though the minimizing values $x,y,z$ would not be well defined despite being, in my view, infinitesimally close to $0$.

Comment: Not sure I am following you.  Letting $x,y,z$ all go to $0$ certainly gets you a small area, but it violates the constraint...your tiny box will have volume near $0$ as well.  That's always the nature of constrained optimization.

Comment: @lulu but what if we have $x$, $y$, $z$ tend to but never equal $0$? How does this violate the constraint $V - xyz = 0$?

Comment: Well, if $x,y,z$ are all less than $\sqrt[3] V$ then $xyz<V$ so...

Comment: What implies $x, y, z$ are all less than $V^{1/3}$? Excuse me if this is obvious. Perhaps it has to do with the box being rectangular?

Comment: You said they tend to $0$.  If they tend to $0$ they must, at some point, be less than any given positive quantity, including $\sqrt[3] V$

Comment: More to the point, perhaps:  there is no a priori guarantee that a constrained minimum exists.  Here it is easy to see that one does, and in general compactness arguments often work.  But in general existence is not certain.  If I ask for the point on the graph of $f(x)=e^{-x}$ which is nearest the $x-$axis then their is no (finite) solution.   That's fine...the method will then fail to produce a minimum.

Comment: As a better example, note that in your problem there is no maximum area!  If, say, $V=1$ we could take $x=y=10^{10}$ and $z=10^{-20}$.  This has enormous surface area (very slightly greater than $10^{20}$) but it still has volume $1$.

Comment: I'm afraid I have some confusions with your explanation. What do you mean by "compactness arguments"? And how do I tie these analogies into why the minimum surface area of a box is not merely $x,y,z \to 0$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68346/discussion-between-sangstar-and-lulu).

Comment: You keep asking the same question about letting $x,y,z$ tend to $0$.  Please try to understand the answers people are giving you.  Letting $x,y,z$ tend to $0$ is not compatible with the constraint.  I really don't know simpler words to express that.  Don't worry about compactness arguments, your question is more basic than that.

Comment: Not interested in chatting, sorry.  Please go over the answers people have given you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the volume of the box is given by:

$$\mathscr{V}=x\cdot y\cdot z\tag1$$

And the surface area:

$$\mathscr{S}=y\cdot z+y\cdot z+x\cdot z+x\cdot z+x\cdot y=2\cdot y\cdot z+2\cdot x\cdot z+x\cdot y\tag2$$

Now, we know that the volume should be $\text{V}$, so we can write:

$$x\cdot y\cdot z=\text{V}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{\text{V}}{y\cdot z}\tag3$$

So, we can write for the surface area:

$$\mathscr{S}=2\cdot y\cdot z+2\cdot\frac{\text{V}}{y\cdot z}\cdot z+\frac{\text{V}}{y\cdot z}\cdot y=2\cdot y\cdot z+2\cdot\frac{\text{V}}{y}+\frac{\text{V}}{z}\tag4$$

And now we need to find:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial\mathscr{S}}{\partial y}=0\\
\\
\frac{\partial\mathscr{S}}{\partial z}=0
\end{cases}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\therefore\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space y=2^\frac{1}{3}\cdot\text{V}^\frac{1}{3}\space\wedge\space z=\frac{\text{V}^\frac{1}{3}}{2^\frac{2}{3}}\tag5
$$

Comment: But can you clue me into the fundamental reasoning behind (5)? Why do we "now need to find" this? What does setting these partial derivatives to $0$ imply? That we have minimum and maxima? But how can an area have a non-trivial minimum of the side lengths tending towards $0$?

Comment: @sangstar Yes you need to find the minimum, so that is what I did in part $(5)$

Comment: but why do we need to *consider* $x$, $y$, and $z$ values such that our surface area is at a minimum? In my intuition, minimizing the surface area would just be letting each of the side lengths $x$, $y$ and $z$ tend to $0$.

Comment: @sangstar One more attempt to explain what others have said but you apparently didn't understand. The question is **not** simply to make the surface area small (which could be accomplished by taking $x,y,z\to0$). It is to make the surface area small **subject to the constraint** stated in the problem, namely: "The box must have a given volume $V$." So, for example, if $V=17$, then a solution must have $xyz=17$, which will not be the case if $x,y,z\to0$.  The same thing happens for any positive value  of the given volume $V$. So your "solution" $x,y,z\to0$ won't work unless $V=0$.

Comment: I think I understand now. $xyz = constant$, where it happens to be $V = constant$. That then implies you can't let $x,y,z$ tend to the same number. Setting a value for $x$ and $y$ automatically will set a value for $z$ since $z = V/xy$, so you can't have $x,y,z \to 0$.